# Calling Fortran DLL in Netbeans IDE 8.0.2 Java

Tags: java, dll, call, netbeans-8

I have an issue. I got a DLL written in Fortran. And I want to call this DLL in Java.

Everything is working fine for other DLLs when I try to call them from a test-Java program. The DLL is existing. Unfortunately, regardless whether I use System.load and mention the whole path or use the loadLibrary method and mention only the DLL's name the same error message is returned:

> java.lang.UnsatisfiedLinkError: C:\Windows\System32\MYDLL.dll: Not enough storage is available to process this command
>       at java.lang.ClassLoader$NativeLibrary.load(Native Method)
>       at java.lang.ClassLoader.loadLibrary0(ClassLoader.java:1929)
>       at java.lang.ClassLoader.loadLibrary(ClassLoader.java:1847)
>       at java.lang.Runtime.loadLibrary0(Runtime.java:870)
>       at java.lang.System.loadLibrary(System.java:1119)
>       at OnlyForTesting.(OnlyForTesting.java:11)
>   Exception in thread "main" Java Result: 1
>   BUILD SUCCESSFUL (total time: 0 seconds)

Here is my code:

```
public class TryToCallDLL {

private native void  method();

public static void main(String[] args){
    System.out.println("Test\n");
    new TryToCallDLL().method();

}

static{
    System.load("C:\\Users\\xxx\\Documents\\NetBeansProjects\\JNItutorial\\src\\TryToCallDLL\\Debug\\MYDLL.dll");
}
```

}

I was searching for anything helpful related to similar errors but nothing was working. There was though one comment stating it could be related to a limited heap storage.

I want to emphasize that this DLL's purpose is calculating using a lot of data.

I also want to add that the DLL is a 32bit version. My PC is 64 bit, I have two Netbeans version (32bit and 64bit), but running the Java program with the 32bit version.

Any suggestions are welcomed. Thank you in advance!

**EDIT:
I increased the heap in the settings: -Xmx1024m
The DLL itself has a size of 1,955 KB.
Still the DLL cannot be loaded.**

Comment: Have you tried to use `JACOB`. Library allows you to call `.dll` in Java. http://sourceforge.net/projects/jacob-project/

Comment: No, I did not try to use it. Calling in general is not the problem as it is working fine for other DLLs. 
In first place I would prefer a solution where I don't have to use further tools.